# My code to change the language of my website does not work

Tags: javascript, json

I've made a language switcher for my website, and it was working until I decided to store the text on a local .json file. It kind of works because it reads the text when loading the page, but when you try to change the language it does not work. This is my JavaScript code:

```
/*This is a list of all the id's I want to change*/
let ids = ["titleText", "llenguatge", "runBut", "trainBut", "resultText", "atention", "warn", "coll0but"]

function catalan() {
    /*I load the json file from the folder. This is the part that doesn't work*/
    $.getJSON("scripts/json/text_cat.json", function(cat) {
        console.log(cat); 
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            /*For every element with that id, change the text corresponding with that id (in the json file, the title is the same as the id)*/
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = cat[ids[i]]
        }
    });
    /*This part does work*/
    console.log("Language has changed to catalan")

}

function spanish() {

    $.getJSON("scripts/json/text_cas.json", function(cas) {
        console.log("funciona?")
        console.log(cas); 
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = cas[ids[i]]
        }
    });

    console.log("Language has changed to spanish")

}

function english() {
    $.getJSON("scripts/json/text_en.json", function(en) {
        console.log(en); 
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(ids[i]).innerHTML = en[ids[i]]
        }
    });

    console.log("Language has changed to english")

}
```

Json file:

```
{
    "titleText":"Blah blah",
    "llenguatge":"Language",
    "runBut":"Guess",
    "trainBut":"Train",
    "resultText":"Result:",
    "atention":"Warning!",
    "warn":"Blah blah blah",
    "coll0but":"Color tools",
}
```

(Edit) Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="Content">
                <div id="nn_container">
                    <div id="canvas" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
                    <div>
                        <span id="result" class="eqCont">
                            <div id="run" class="half"></div>
                            <div id="answer" class="half">
                                <div id="lastColor">
                                    <b id="resultText"></b>
                                    <span id="clar" class="reult"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="info">
                    <div id="Warning1" class="warning">
                        <strong id="atention"></strong> <p class="text" id="warn"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Could you include your file structure?

Comment: What does not work? Your console.log of the language needs to be after  console.log(cas); or (en) etc because the A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. Any errors if you press F12?

Comment: The refresh of the HTML content, which should be edited by this script is not changing when the function is called. It just doesn't execute the loop.